# Building large application on Solaris is hanging without any information

Tags: c++, build, compilation, solaris

I am trying to compile a rather big application on Solaris. Compiling it on AIX caused a problem that the command line buffer was too small (`ARG_MAX`).

On Solaris it compiles most of application successfullym but then it just hangs and without any error hangs an do nothing for at least an hour.

I am running it on SunOS 5.10 Sparc 32 bit.

Any ideas on how to find out what's going on or what might be causing such behavior?

Comment: Were the AIX and SunOS failures in the same place?  What application?

Comment: Also, what compiler / version are you using on each platform?

Comment: I have seen cases where the optimizer "hangs" on some files.
You can try disabling optimization for the problematic source file(s).

Comment: compiler is CC..and yes optimizer causes the hang..i used -fast and -xO3... any suggestion as to what should I try or insight why does it get "hanged"... also if you could answer this so I can mark it as answer that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who encounter this in future.
The problem was optimization flag causes it to take a REALLY long time to compile. I am talking 1+ hour for one cpp file.

This is big project. 
In addition there was an issue with Sys Admin on SUN box not giving me enough CPU share.
Increasing that solved this problem, well made it quicker and within reasonable time bounds.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if the compilation is hanging, or your app itself.

If the app is hanging just follow the usual debugging steps: Either run it in your debugger and watch when it dies, or add print statements.

If the compiler dies, does it always die on the same file? If you compile that file by itself does it still hang? If so, try `truss`ing the *compiler* when you try to build the file that hangs. You may find that it's blocking on I/O waiting for some nonexistant file or something similar.

Comment: it does not die ..just hangs...and its not app its compilation that is hanging.. and its doing it on same file.. what is truss never heard of it

Answer (score 0):

What you may have to do is:

1. Comment out or delete 99% of the code and compile that
2. Add around 5% of the code back in and compile that

   if the last thing you added caused the hour hang then split it up
3. Back to step 2